# IIS CS Source file on server without compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to place ASPX and C# source code file on server instead compiling a DLL (like we do with PHP)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/showasp.asp?filename=demo_intro

Comment: Take a look here http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started

Comment: Thanks but i have an execution error: "Could not load type 'WebApplication3.Default'. I think it is looking for a dll inside bin subfolder. How can i tell it to compile cs file by the fly ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. but why do you want to do like that.

Comment: Because i remember to have do this in 2007. I am wondering if it was a dream or real because i do not manage to do it again. Off course it is best to put compiled file on server.